# Adjust color to powertools extension for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

I use Visual Studio 2012, and the productivity powertools extension. 
I often use the "quick find" function that comes with this extension - the little blue 'dot' that shows in the scrollbar, when you highlight a word, or part of it, showing all the usages for the selection in that page.

How can I change the color of this dot? It is only nearly visible with the dark-theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools - Options - Productivity Power Tools - Enhanced Scroll Bar - Words matching the caret location color in the scrollbar.

Took me a while to find this too! I spent ages going through the normal colour settings convinced it pulled it from in there somewhere.